# Delete a property from JSON with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i have the next code:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f982a5fe64d4c0315caebac"), 
    "baneado" : false, 
    "email" : "rodolfo.computacion+003@gmail.com", 
    "password" : "$2a$10$Q6Uk.OUVFmZAtREHnogEuOabPvnQlvQ15yKPxo/fFcZ5xEciYdOHu", 
    "nombre" : "Rodolfo", 
    "apellido" : "Rodriguez", 
    "propiedades" : [
        {
            "beta" : true
        }, 
        {
            "promociones" : {
                "activo" : true
            }
        }
    ], 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-10-27T14:10:39.108+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-10-27T14:14:55.096+0000"), 

}
```

and i try to delete "promociones" if exists, but a have a error, here my code:

```
var promesaUser =  User.update({ _id: elemento._user }, { $pull: {  propiedades:{promociones: { $exists: true} }  } }).exec()
```

and it send me the next error:

**error 1 MongoError: '$pull' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$pull: {: ...}} at Function.MongoError.create (/home/rodolfo/desarrollo/api-backend-ecdf/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:45:10**

Im starting with this, sorry the mistake, I dont nknow what happen...in advanced thanks!

Comment: You can try specifying the `$exists` condition in the update query's filter.

Comment: in the collection, some registry have this "propiedades", some others dont, if exits, delete only that property...

Comment: The query should be like this: `User.update({ _id: elemento._user,  "propiedades.promociones": { $exists: true }  }, {...}` )

Comment: the same error, but thanks